# Issue while generating a custom generator in Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to create a custom generator called `migration` for Sails JS. I ran the following command in the root directory of my Sails app:

```
sails generate generator migration
```

Then, it created a directory called `migration` in the app directory. But when I run:

```
sails generate migration
```

it says:

```
error: No generator called `migration` found; perhaps you meant `sails generate api migration`?
```

Any idea why this is happening? Do I need to do anything more to make it work?

Comment: what you want to achieve with `sails generate migration`?

Comment: I want to create a template file in `\migrations` directory in my sails app

Comment: When I run `sails generate migration create-device-table`, it should create a migration file in `/migrations` directory with content similar to one in https://github.com/kunklejr/node-db-migrate